# Configure unique session for QuickFix Python TargetSubId

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am attempting to configure *quickfix* python to be compatible with CME's market segment gateway (*MSGW*), this would entail deriving a unique session based on **TargetSubID**. From the *quickfix* python documentation it appears uniqueness of a session is based on **BeginString**, **SenderCompID**, **TargetCompID**. I would like to configure *quickfix* such that **TargetSubID** is used in constructing a unique session.

From the [quickfix python documentation](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html), it is not readily apparent how I can get this configuration. I have found that other quickfix implementation (albeit with different code bases) have this feature ([Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/quickfix-component.html)).

Any suggestions or solutions as to coaxing *quickfix* python into constructing a unique session with another parameter would be greatly appreciated.